# token request with Perl an Net::SSLeay

Tags: perl, api, rest, paypal

I am trying to request the token for the new REST API with Perl an Net::SSLeay (my provider in only supporting Net::SSLeay, modules like NET::PayPal are not installed) but the request fails. What am I doing wrong? Especially I am not sure, hot to set 'grant_type'...

```
use Net::SSLeay qw(get_https make_form make_headers post_https);
use MIME::Base64;
use strict;

my $site = "api.sandbox.paypal.com";
my $port = "443";
my $path = "/v1/oauth2/token?grant_type=client_credentials";
my $uname = "my_client_id";
my $password = "my_secret";

$uname = encode_base64($uname);
$password = encode_base64($password);
my $cred = "Basic $uname:$password";

my ($page, $result, %headers) = post_https($site, $port, $path, make_headers(
'Accept'=>"application/json",
'Accept-Language'=>"en_US",
'Authorization'=>"$cred"
));
```

Is here someone how can help?

Best regards,
Lars

Comment: Please show error code!

Answer (score 0):

you need to base64 the string `user:password`, not separately. So in your example it should be:

```
my $uname = "EN_Qsr0vnzjAI8iixqZHd2yoNtIZYDkdAreSpqbe3SiU";
my $password ="EDQccsa77f81xM-QU9kADtioNtIZYDkdAreSpqbe3SiU";

my $cred = "Basic " . encode_base64($uname . ":" . $password);
```